# Seeding data across Sequelize associations

Tags: javascript, database, orm, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize (new to ORM's) and currently have three tables: card and tags, that have a many-to-many relationship that is established with the third table, card_tags. My question is two fold:

1. How do I seed data across associations?
2. How do I create new data (i.e. an API function) that establishes new data across associated data bases?

Please see the below for my models and let me know if I'm leaving anything out. Thanks!

**cards model:**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Card = sequelize.define('card', {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    link: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });

  Card.associate = (models) => {
    Card.belongsToMany(models.tag, { through: 'card_tag', as: 'tag' });
  };

  return Card;
};
```

**tags model:**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Tag = sequelize.define('tag', {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });

  Tag.associate = (models) => {
    Tag.belongsToMany(models.card, { through: 'card_tag', as: 'card'});
  };

  return Tag;
};
```

**card_tags model:**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const CardTag = sequelize.define('card_tag', {
    cardId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    tagId: DataTypes.INTEGER
  });

  return CardTag;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and quickest way to do is to to insert bulk data in each relation.
You can write sequelize queries to bulkInsert keeping in mind that primary key for each foriegn key is created first.

You can use faker npm module to generate random data.